# Phenom II X4 840 Reading at 2.2 Ghz

Tags: cpu, motherboard, amd-phenom

I recently bought a Phenom II X4 840 3.2 Ghz. Not too bad for a 50 dollar Processor. I've now done a motherboard swap on an old HP Pavillion, but I'm running a Phenom II X4 840 2.2 Ghz. I don't want to contact the seller about this issue until I'm 100% sure that it's not something on my end. Possibly underclocked or anything of that nature. I'm using an MSI 880GM-E41 AM3 Motherboard and on Windows 10. [image: System Configuration and MSI Control Center]

I've included a picture of the System Readout and my settings for my MSI Control Center.

Comment: There's no reason to contact the seller. It's currently set at base clock speed of 200Mhz and a multiplier of x11. 200Mhz x 11 = 2.2Ghz. Adjust either the base or the multiplier to get where you want to be at. Do it from the BIOS, though; not that control center.

Comment: I'll see what I can do in the bios. Couldn't find much for overclocking in the bios. That control center locks up the PC if I try to change much over 5 mhz in 2 minute intervals. Also; Thank you. The last thing I wanted to do was accuse someone of selling the wrong product when it's something on my end.

Comment: Looking at the manual for your motherboard, there should be a setting for Adjust CPU Ratio.

Comment: Ah; I'll look into that after this download is done. =D I'm assuming I won't lock up if I change the settings in the bios rather than that control panel. (I kind of feel like that control panel is setting me up for failure.)

Comment: Yeah, with a change to the system like that I wouldn't even attempt to do it from some control center in Windows. It should be fine if you do it from the BIOS.

Comment: Verify your using the current version the firmware.  The base clock for that's cPU is 3.2 GHz so if the CPU is being identified as the CPU you purchased then it's legitimate hardware.  As explained the CPU is running at the correct (currently configured) frequency.  Fake CPUs cannot identify themselves as something else, fake products are after, easy solutions (remove the die and place a fake lid).

Comment: I can increase everything in the bios but if I go above 2.7 it stops and says the ocean failed.

Comment: Overclock. Sorry last comment was made from my phone. I got it up to it's actual speed and with the chassis fan I'm running 27 degrees celsius with the division running. What's a safe temperature to let this run? I don't have the stock heatsink, but it's not liquid either; just an aluminum heatsink with 4 bronze looking tubes. Sorry for all the questions it just seems like I hit some people with some good knowledge on OC

Comment: The 27 Celsius you're running it at now is perfect. That's what my i7 runs at with liquid cooling. For your processor you probably don't want to get above 60 Celsius.